# Why is my class not applying to a certain element is sass

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

So I'm using React and sass and I tried to use `activeClassName` property on a `<NavLink>` and I realized my active class is not working because the active class came before the default class. How do I fix this problem?

Here's the code

HTML

```
        <div className="nav-dropdown">
        <div className="dropdown-links-list">
            <div> <NavLink to="/" exact activeClassName="dropdown-link-active">
               <span>Home</span>
            </NavLink> </div>
            <NavLink to="/order" exact  activeClassName="dropdown-link-active">
               <span>Order</span>
            </NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/about" exact  activeClassName="dropdown-link-active">
                <span>About</span>
            </NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/FAQ" exact activeClassName="dropdown-link-active">
                <span>FAQ</span>
            </NavLink>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.nav-dropdown {
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  height: 100%;

  .dropdown-links-list a {
    display: grid;
    margin-top: -1px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    height: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
    @include grid-center;
    span {
      color: #000;
      font-size: 17px;
      text-align: center;
    }
  }
}

.dropdown-link-active {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: did you tried with .test.dropdown-link-active {}?

Comment: Yeah, and I've removed the "test" class I accidentally left it there sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is rewrite the styles in a more BEM way. Your NavLink will have a default class and a modifier class separated by two hyphens.

```
<div className="nav-dropdown">
    <div className="nav-dropdown__links">
        <NavLink
            to="/home"
            exact
            className="nav-dropdown__link"
            activeClassName="nav-dropdown__link--active"
         >
           <span>Home</span>
         </NavLink>
    </div>
</div>
```

The scss would look like this:

```
.nav-dropdown {
  //style
  &__links {
    //style
  }
  &__link {
    background: #fff;
    height: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    span {
      color: #000;
      font-size: 17px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    &--active {
      background-color: yellow;
    }
  }
}
```